# open an subform based on the selection in list box in Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, listbox, subform

so basicly i have a problem with opening an subform. I have a Main form that contains 2 list boxes. Selection on the first list box cause change in the displayed records in the second list box. And selection on the second list box should fill my subform with data. My problem is that i cant get second list box to affect the data on the subform.

For example: 1st listbox is a supplier list, 2nd listbox is goods received. Depends on the selected supplier i receive diffrent goods on the 2nd list. And after selection of the specific goods on the list i want to receive a table of all received boxes of selected goods of selected supplier in my subform. (Right now selection on the first list cause my subform to show me all goods from selected supplier, while selection on second list dosen't do anyting with the subform)

Answer (score 0):

You want to filter the subform based on the listbox selection.

Set `LinkMasterFields` (of the subform control) to the name of your listbox control and `LinkChildFields` to the field in the the underlying recordset of the the subform that represents the goods.

Then when you select specific goods in the listbox, only records pertaining to those goods will show in the subform.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about that but had problem with a list being unbound. And also had a wrong bound column in the listbox selected. It started working after seting bound column to a same value as the one in subform.

Answer (score 0):

Use Master Child relation. Select the subform and in Data tab select the Master and Child relation and then the subform will be filtered based on the selection.